# Console throws exception: java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to add and print values of array variables

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file

I am a rookie java programmer working on an assignment. However, I am stuck with one small error which I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

In this program, I am trying to read the file and storing the data of the file in variables with the array size equal to the number of lines in the file.

For example: If there are 10 lines in the file, then the array size of the variables should also be 10. After storing them, I want to display them. (I already know how to display the data).

But I have a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

I think that the error in my code exists either in the `setVariable` method of the `Athlete` class or the `readFile` function in `main`.

The `setVariable` method is used to set the data extracted from the file to the array type variables (First Name, Last Name, Id Number, Citizenship, Time).

The `readFile` function is used to read the data from the file, store that data in a temporary variable, and send the value of the temporary variable to `setVariable` as a parameter.

The file contains the following values in respective order: 
("FirstName LastName IdNumber Citizenship Time")

```
class Athlete
{
private

String[] firstName;
String[] lastName;
String[] citizen;
int[] id;
float[] time;

public
void Athlete(int s) //Setting the size of the array variables.
{
    firstName = new String[s];
    lastName = new String[s];
    citizen = new String[s];
    id = new int[s];
    time = new float[s];
}
void setVariables(String fName,String lName, int idNumber, String citizenship, float t, int lineNumber)
{
    firstName[lineNumber]=fName;
    lastName[lineNumber]=lName;
    id[lineNumber]=idNumber;
    citizen[lineNumber]=citizenship;
    time[lineNumber]=t;
    System.out.println(firstName[lineNumber]+"\t"+lastName[lineNumber]+"\t"+id[lineNumber]+"\t"+citizen[lineNumber]+"\t"+time[lineNumber]);
}
}

//Main CLASS
public class marathon {

static Scanner console;
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //STEP-1: FILE
    openFile(); //Step 1.1: Open the File
    System.exit(0);
}

static void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        console = new Scanner (new File("C:/Eclipse_Wokspace/Assignment-2/src/Marathon.txt"));
        //Step 1.2: Read the File
        readFile();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File did not open because of "+e);
    }
}   static void readFile()
{
    int size=0;
    Athlete athlete = new Athlete();
    while (console.hasNext())
    {
        String a,b,d; int c; float e; //Read the data in the file and store them in temporary variables.
        a=console.next(); //First Name
        b=console.next(); //Last Name
        c=console.nextInt(); //ID-Number
        d=console.next(); //Citizenship
        e=console.nextFloat(); //Time
        //Step 1.3: Store File Data
        athlete.setVariables(a, b, c, d, e, size);
        size++;
    }

    athlete.Athlete(size);
}
}
```

[Marathon txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzBPX.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9B0T.png)

Reason why I cant embed the images in this post
[Not allowing me to upload any image on this post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6av5C.png)

Comment: This looks like a lot more context than should be needed to reproduce and debug the error. It is hard to search large amounts of code when much of it is unrelated to the exact problem at hand. Could you prune down the code to a minimal verifiable example?

Comment: This isn't the problem, just a side note: Only your `firstName` instance variable is private in the above. All the others have the default access modifier. Similarly, only the `Athlete` method is public. Java isn't like C++, there aren't sections you put the declarations in. Each one has its own access modifiers. Separately, beware that `Athlete` doesn't have a constructor. If you meant the `Athlete` *method* to be a constructor, remove the `void` from in front of it (constructors don't have return types).

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BlackVegetable I have edited the code above just to make it shorter. I removed the import statements. I removed much of the main class where I am sure that there are no errors.

Comment: @KeshavMathur that's a good start. Thank you. Could you include the error in the post itself instead of in an external link? Knowing the exact expected input/output and the exact text of the error in the post itself will make it much more likely to be answered. I'll help with the formatting a little as well, unless you or someone else beats me to it.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Thank you so much if you could help me in formatting. However, I took your advice and tried to embed them in this post. But stack overflow wont allow that to happen unless I have a reputation of 10. Plus, I don't know why I really got 3 down votes?

Comment: @helpThisProgrammer Ah, sorry. I meant to copy-paste (or just rewrite by hand) the text of the error, not an image of the error. I'll take a gamble and click your link ;)

Comment: @BlackVegetable java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @BlackVegetable it shows up in the console window and not in my code area.

Comment: What is the line of code referenced by the error? There should be a line number that is truncated in your linked image.

Comment: I also came across this link very recently that may be of help to you going forward: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @BlackVegetable If you see the error image^^. It does not mention any line that has an error

Comment: I wish I could remember how to invite you to chat. If the option appears here, I will. Sorry to ask this, but could you re-insert the `main` method? I think your file loading is your problem and that isn't included in the current code.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I added the main class...

Comment: Thanks. Please print out the value of `console` after you assign it its value. My guess is we somehow have a `null` value in the `console` variable and that is causing the NPE when we try to execute methods on it.

Comment: Ah, your setVariable function is attempting to modify uninitialized arrays. That should throw an NPE as well. I would read up on Java constructors and revisit your approach. You are currently using the default constructor which does not initialize those arrays. That's definitely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Athlete` constructor expects a size argument. However, your first creation of an Athlete uses no arguments, so this defaults to Java's "default constructor" which does nothing but call super, basically.

So you need to use your constructor that actually allocates those arrays you are shortly going to populate. The problem is, the way the code is written, you don't know the size until after you've read your entire file and attempted to modify the `Athlete`.

There are many approaches you could take and a number of style and semantic fixes I could propose for this file, but I suggest starting with a single pass through your file to get the size, and then use that to call the constructor with the size as its argument. Then you can safely mutate those arrays in a second pass.  This should get you started.

Comment: What do u mean by "call super?".  So I need to use my constructor to allocate my arrays? Where do I allocate these arrays? From what I understand is that I have to create another method and call that method which would allocate the size of the array? I am confused :/

Comment: "starting with a single pass through your file to get the size, and then use that to call the constructor with the size as its argument. Then you can safely mutate those arrays in a second pass. This should get you started". I am literally a rookie and have no idea what a single pass is or what a second pass is.

Comment: Don't worry about super for now.  And by pass, I meant reading through your file. Reading it from start to end would be "one pass", doing so again would be a "second pass". So first find out how large your file is (in terms of newlines) so you can call your constructor with the size parameter. Then go ahead and populate the arrays as you are currently.

Comment: So I have to check the amount of '\n'? and with every '\n' I increase my count?

Comment: while (scannerInput.hasNextLine()) {count++;}. Then I pass the count variable?